# Difference between xargs /bin/ls and exec ls?

Tags: linux, macos, find, xargs

Hi this may be a very newbie question, but why doesnt the xargs /bin/ls work in this case? I thought it was supposed to be faster? Also what are those /fd/3 directories?

```
sh-3.2# find / -name 'GOALS*' -exec ls -l {} \;
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
.... This returns me the expected result....
```

However this returns the whole list of files in the directory

```
sh-3.2# find / -name GOALS* -type f | xargs /bin/ls -l
```

I am on a MacOS.

Comment: You appear to be missing quotes around the wildcard in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to quote the `*` in the second `find` command,
2. the `/dev/fd/*` are devices which corresponds with `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` etc. thouse devices are simlinked and are different for each process,
3. the `-type f` says, the result has to be regular file, thus the `/dev/fd/*` are not in the result as they are block devices,
4. the `xargs ls -l` does the same as your `ls -l {}`... I even doubt the better performance in this case, but `xargs` is smarter and there are reasons to use it, eg. correct handling of files with whitespaces inside it,

If you are debugging the second version of your `find`, first of all see the output w/o the `| xargs ls -l` part

Answer (score 1):

Your first command executes a new `ls` command for every filename which matches the name you provided.  This includes directories, symbolic links, devices, and anything else that can be found.  The `ls` command gets executed as files are found, so you will see listings as the files are found.

The second command only matches file with the specified name.  Because you did not quote `GOALS*`, if you run from a directory with a matching entry, it will replace the `GOALS*` entry in the command.  `xargs` calls `ls` will a long list of file names.  You won't see results until either the find finishes, or a sufficiently long list of matches is found. Because of parsing rules filename which contain whitespace will cause problems.

These three commands should be equivalent for files without white space in the name.  The third option does not work on all operating systems, but handles white space in the name.

```
find / -name 'GOALS*' -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
find / -name 'GOALS*' -type f | xargs /bin/ls -l
find / -name 'GOALS*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/ls -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell (bash) builtin `exec` replaces the current shell with the given argument. Try exec sleep 1, for example. The executable `xargs` is part of the GNU findutils package. It will execute the command given to it as the first argument with argument read from standard input.

E.g.:

```
$ echo -e "calves drink milk\npeople eat cows" | xargs -L1 cowsay
 ___________________
< calves drink milk >
 -------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
 _________________
< people eat cows >
 -----------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

The example you provided "does not work" because the argument list consisting of all files on your computer and special files under /sys and /proc grow too large. You cannot ask a command to work on arbitrarily large list of arguments because there is a limit (getconf ARG_MAX -- bytes I think).

Sometimes, you do want to do something with a large list of arguments though, and a solution is to process chunks of the list and not the whole list at once.

E.g.:

```
$ cat tmp/moo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo processing $# arguments

$ seq 0 10000 | xargs -L 1001 sh tmp/moo.sh  | cat -n
     1  processing 1001 arguments
     2  processing 1001 arguments
     3  processing 1001 arguments
     4  processing 1001 arguments
     5  processing 1001 arguments
     6  processing 1001 arguments
     7  processing 1001 arguments
     8  processing 1001 arguments
     9  processing 1001 arguments
    10  processing 992 arguments
```

The last part of your question about "those fd" folders is about **f**ile **d**escriptors. When you run find, it will look in /proc and see file descriptors (standard input, standard out, regular files for reading and writing) of running processes. By the time find exits and xargs takes over, some of those processes may no longer exist. Thus the errors. Files in /dev/fd are actually only symlinks:

```
$ ll /dev/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 jaroslav jaroslav 64 Nov 18 01:57 0 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 jaroslav jaroslav 64 Nov 18 01:57 1 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 jaroslav jaroslav 64 Nov 18 01:57 2 -> /dev/pts/7
lr-x------ 1 jaroslav jaroslav 64 Nov 18 01:57 3 -> /proc/21677/fd
geee: ~
$ file /dev/pts/7
/dev/pts/7: character special
geee: ~
$ sudo echo "MOOOOOOO" >>  /dev/pts/7
Password:
MOOOOOOO
```

What I did there is I wrote to the standard output of my terminal. I have no idea what process 21677 is, but by the time `find /` finishes, I'm sure it will be destroyed even if it were present at the time when find scanned /proc.